# Why does <button type='button'> trigger a postback?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a `<button type='button'>` in a FORM element and it does not trigger a postback, which is what I want.

What I really want is to tie some jQuery script to the button.  But the moment I do that, clicking the button causes a postback.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnProceed" value="Proceed" />
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>

$('#btnCancel').click(function () {
    $('#btnProceed').prop('disabled', 'true');
    $('#msg').css('display', 'inline');
    this.disabled = true;
    return false;
});
```

Is this how it is supposed to work?  How do I prevent the postback (without moving the button to outside the FORM)?

Comment: Do you have another submit button in your form? share code for your form

Comment: Yes, btnProceed is the submit button. Before I tied the jQuery script to btnCancel, there was no postback when it was clicked.

Comment: are you sure your click handler is getting called? try adding a logging/alert statement in teh click handler and see

Comment: Yes. The two buttons are disabled, and the message div is showed, and then a postback. But if I removed the jQuery code, click the Cancel button does nothing and does not cause a postback.

Comment: give it a `name` property other than `submit`. it might be using that as default.

Comment: You can use `preventDefault` to avoid form being submitted in the jquery function.

Comment: The problem went away when I made a change to the form's action attribute.  It's a bit complicated and I will try my best to explain in this single paragraph comment field.  The page (view2) was launched by a `return View("view2")` from Action A1.  Initially, view2 had `Html.BeginForm("A1",..)`.  Clicking the Cancel button with no jQuery code doesn't cause a  postback, but with jQuery code causes a POST to A1.  When I change the action to something other than A1, eg `Html.BeginForm("A99",..)` it works fine.  Thanks to all for trying to help.  If someone has an explanation I will be happier.

Comment: Exceeded the 5 minutes to update the above comment.  By Action A1, I meant MVC Action A1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#btnCancel').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#btnProceed').prop('disabled', 'true');
    $('#msg').css('display', 'inline');
    this.disabled = true;
    return false;
});
```

Also, try

```
   <input type="button" class="btn" id="btnCancel">Cancel</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.disabled = true;
```

to

```
this.disabled = false;
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following code

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnProceed" value="Proceed" />
<input type="button" class="btn" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
$('#btnCancel').on('click',function () {
$('#btnProceed').prop('disabled', 'true');
$('#msg').css('display', 'inline');
this.disabled = false;
return false;
});
```